# tikz: Better raised text effect

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

If you look carefully at the raised text in this image, you can see that it has two drop shadows:  as well as the black one to the southeast of the text, there is a white one to the northwest. I know how to insert one drop shadow in tikz using e.g.

```
drop shadow={shadow xshift=-0.5mm,shadow yshift=-0.5mm,black}
```

Is there any easy way to add two shadows of the kind specified?  (NB. Being able to specify the 'light direction' via `shadow xshift`,`shadow yshift` is very useful.)

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Duplicate shadows

With key `preaction` another shadow can be inserted, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \node[
    fill=darkgray,
    preaction={
      drop shadow={
        fill=white,
        opacity=1,
        shadow xshift=-.5mm,
        shadow yshift=.5mm,
      },
    },  
    drop shadow={
      fill=black,
      opacity=1,
      shadow xshift=.5mm,
      shadow yshift=-.5mm
    },
  ] at (1,1) {\rule{8mm}{0mm}\rule{0mm}{8mm}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Two shadows]

This can be further simplified. `drop shadow` uses `general shadow`, which is already implemented via `preaction`. Thus the `preaction` part can be dropped:

```
  \node[
    fill=darkgray,
    drop shadow={ 
      fill=white, 
      opacity=1,  
      shadow xshift=-.5mm,
      shadow yshift=.5mm, 
    },
    drop shadow={
      fill=black,
      opacity=1, 
      shadow xshift=.5mm,
      shadow yshift=-.5mm
    },
  ] at (1,1) {\rule{8mm}{0mm}\rule{0mm}{8mm}};
```

Also a style can be defined to simplify the use case, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\pgfkeysdefnargs{/my/get value}{2}{%
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{#1}{#2}%
}
\tikzset{
  /tikz/drop raised shadow/.style={
    drop shadow={%
      fill=white,
      opacity=1,
      #1,%
      /my/get value={/tikz/shadow xshift}{\xshift},
      /my/get value={/tikz/shadow yshift}{\yshift},
      shadow xshift=-\xshift,
      shadow yshift=-\yshift,
    },
    drop shadow={%
      fill=black,
      opacity=1,
      #1%
    }
  }  
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \node[
    fill=darkgray,
    drop shadow={
      fill=white,
      opacity=1,
      shadow xshift=-.5mm,
      shadow yshift=.5mm,
    },
    drop shadow={
      fill=black,
      opacity=1,
      shadow xshift=.5mm,
      shadow yshift=-.5mm
    },
  ] at (1,1) {\rule{8mm}{0mm}\rule{0mm}{8mm}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \node[
    fill=darkgray,
    drop raised shadow={
      shadow xshift=.5mm,
      shadow yshift=-.5mm,
    },
  ] at (1,1) {\rule{8mm}{0mm}\rule{0mm}{8mm}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Text shadows

The following version without package `tikz` sets the text three times, first in color white, moved to the left and raised, then in color black to the right and below, finally the the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\RaisedText}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \leavevmode
    \rlap{\kern-.1pt\raise.1pt\hbox{\color{white}#1}}%
    \rlap{\kern.1pt\raise-.1pt\hbox{\color{black}#1}}%
    \hbox{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{lightgray}{%
  \color{darkgray}\RaisedText{Raised Text}%
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

A variant with package `pdfrender`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfrender}

\newcommand*{\RaisedText}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \leavevmode
    \rlap{\kern-.1pt\raise.1pt\hbox{%
      \pdfrender{
        TextRenderingMode=Stroke,
        LineWidth=.2pt,
        StrokeColor=white,
      }#1%
    }}%
    \rlap{\kern.1pt\raise-.1pt\hbox{%
      \pdfrender{
        TextRenderingMode=Stroke,
        LineWidth=.2pt,
        StrokeColor=black,
      }#1%
    }}%
    \rlap{%
      \pdfrender{
        TextRenderingMode=Stroke,
        LineWidth=.2pt,
      }#1%
    }%
    \hbox{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{lightgray}{%
  \color{darkgray}\RaisedText{Raised Text}%
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result pdfrender]

Comment: Unfortunately I'm actually trying to use the effect on more complex tikz elements, not on text... sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @Tarass: The preaction answer is both perfect and general.

Comment: @Mohan I do not see how the preaction answer could be changed to fit raised text - could you elaborate?