# How to make a glowing text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, decorations

I'd like to achieve such a result, like when you apply a glowing effect to a text in an image editor.
[image]

---

As I am already using `tikz` package in my document, it would be prefferable to use tikz's library.

I found out, that there is a `shadows.blur` one which would create a soft shadow. Then I would shift it so that it looks like a glowing effect.

However, unfortunately, this attempt makes a rectangle rather than the text's shadow.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[preaction={blur shadow={shadow xshift=-.5mm,shadow yshift=.5mm}}] at (1,1) {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could try tikz shadow or contour package. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227375/why-cant-contour-text-along-curve-path

Comment: @rakatex could you tell more about `shadows` tiks library?

Comment: This link might be of good help to you. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184897/tikz-better-raised-text-effect

Comment: @rakatex unfortunately, the author attaches the image with the desired smooth shadow, but doesn't provide the code and asks rather about embossing.

Comment: Is there a way to do it also on pictures ? In Word, I can insert a picture, say a PNG with alpha layer, right click, Format Picture..., Effects (pentagon), Glow (presets), it will follow the contour of the picture (orange) not just create a rectangle around it (green). [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI63h.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI63h.png)

Answer (score 14):

You could use a combination of tikz and contour package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\mycontour#1{\textcolor{black}{\contour{green!20}{#1}}}
\node (1) at (0cm, 0cm) {};
\node (2) at (2cm,0cm) {};   
\draw[
decoration={text effects along path,
text={Text},
text align=center,
text effects/.cd,
text along path, scale text to path,
characters={font=\Huge,character command=\mycontour},
},decorate,
]  (1) to (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or just

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\contournumber{27}
\newcommand{\mycontour}[2][green!20]{\textcolor{black}{\contour{#1}{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\Huge\mycontour{Text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat, yes. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat, sometimes its not working without decorations.text. Could you tell me why?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat yes, your code is more simpler and straightforward. \documentclass[12pt,border=12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\newcommand{\mycontour}[2][green!20]{\textcolor{black}{\contour{#1}{#2}}} 
\begin{document} 
\Huge\mycontour{Text} 
\end{document}

Comment: Just add it as an alternative to your answer, if you like.

Comment: How to do that, I edit my answer?

Comment: I just added it. Then you do not need to reintroduce the line breaks.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat change the text "Some text" to "Text"

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Since the arrow is just a glyph, maybe this question is related to q/543952

Answer (score 9):

Just one step further from the previous answer.
This one uses the idea of
[Faded or blurred lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80171/faded-or-blurred-lines/)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\begin{document}

\Huge

Assume pdf\TeX

\def\exText{LIPSUM}

\makeatletter

    Reverse engineer the contour package.

    Here is an MWE
    \leavevmode
    \begingroup
        \color{green}%
        \con@coloroff
        \pdfliteral{%
            q % enter a scope
            1 j % Set line join style
            1 J % Set line cap style
            1 Tr % Set text rendering mode
            2.5 w % Set line width (in PostScript Point)
        }%
        \rlap{\exText}%
        \pdfliteral{%
            Q % leave the scope
        }%
    \endgroup
    \mbox{\exText}


    Now use TikZ.
    \leavevmode
    \pgfsys@beginscope% = pdf literal q
    \pgfsetroundjoin% = 1 J
    \pgfsetroundcap% = 1 j
    \pdfliteral{1 Tr}% no pgf alternative
    \foreach\ind in{10,...,1}{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\per{(11-\ind)*5}%
        \color{green!\per}%
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\ind/2}%
        \rlap{\exText}%
    }%
    \pgfsys@endscope % = pdf literal Q
    \exText

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I think that one can use the trick of superimposing relatively shifted characters for the contour, but there will be limits. I played some time ago with `copy shadow` and the problem was that it depends on the path whether it looks good. But yes, for these characters the results are good.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Also try this ``` Right arrows? \def\exText{$\rightarrow\Rightarrow$} \pdfliteral{q 1 j 1 J 1 Tr}\foreach\per in{5,10,...,50}{\color{green!\per}\pgfsetlinewidth{(50-\per)/10}\rlap{\exText}}\pdfliteral{Q}\exText ```

Comment: I am always wondering why it is that `asymptote` and `pstricks` can access the path of glyphs but Ti*k*Z has such a hard time. I know your nice solutions of "decomposing the world in triangles" but I am always hoping that one day Ti*k*Z will know what the path for a glyph for an `A`, say, of a given point is. And as for your last point, can't one use `copy shadow` to do that for an arbitrary content? But yes, it looks good!

Comment: I have no idea why `pstricks` has access to so much things, this and z-sorting of 3D objects. Asymptote can do more because it's standalone. But `pstricks`...? I don't understand.

Comment: `copy shadow` is `O(m)`. Glowing by varying line width is `O(n)`. Combining `copy shadow` and varying line width is `O(mn)`. The hight complexity keeps `m` and `n` small, which is bad. The triangulation trick is the worst because it alone is `O(mn)`. I only do them for the mere possibility.

Comment: But why do you need both? Isn't `contour` just a large number of `copy shadow`s in Ti*k*Z terminology? (Things which do not look great according to my experience are e.g. spirals with varying distances between the lines.)

Comment: `contour` is not a large number of `copy shadow` in this answer. Notice the `1 Tr` command. This pdf literal draws the glyph (treated as bezier curves) instead of filling it.

Comment: Yes, that's a fair point.

Comment: This is great. I'm a year late here, but is there any way to turn this into a TikZ command?

Comment: @geodude I hope so! But it what way you want to use it? Make any node text  glowing?

Comment: yes, exactly. It would be nice to have a compact command that does it.

Comment: @geodude Like this? https://gist.github.com/Symbol1/625d06d848c441c28d3053e975172d5d

Comment: Yes, very nice!